# How to run Spring Boot .jar with Java Modules?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to create a simple Spring Boot application and run it with Java Modules on the latest Java version.

I have created a Main class:

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Module: " + Main.class.getModule());
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
  }
}
```

And a `module-info.java`:

```
module spring.jpms {
  requires spring.core;
  requires spring.boot;
  requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
  requires spring.context;
  requires spring.beans;

  opens org.example to
      spring.core,
      spring.beans,
      spring.context;
}
```

When I run the Main class using an IDE generated command with module path, it works fine, the name of my application module printed out.

```
Module: module spring.jpms
...
```

When I run my application using `mvn spring-boot:run` or `java -jar <target>.jar`, the application is executed in the class-path mode. The module name is "unnamed":

```
...
Module: unnamed module @7923f745
...
```

I would like to know if there is a way to run a .jar file built by the Spring Boot Maven plugin with Java Modules, that is so the .jar files are loaded via `module-path`

See the complete example here: https://github.com/agavrilov76/spring-jpms

Comment: Note `-jar <file>` will _always_ put the JAR file on the class-path. If it's a modular JAR file, and Spring can handle being on the module-path, then use `--module <main-module>/<main-class>`. The short name for `--module` is `-m`. The `/<main-class>` can be omitted if the module has been configured with a main class (e.g., when creating the JAR file, the `--main-class` option was specified).